# User based color customisation in android application?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've 5 screens in my project, each screen has background colour in home screen. I've bring option to user change the color of each screen background at runtime. Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You can use shared preference

Answer (score 0):

So you want user have choice what color to be background color of the other screens? If so just use color picker from available open source, like this https://github.com/LarsWerkman/HoloColorPicker